# C# structs returned by method performance

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, struct

Lets say that i have a struct like that:

```
public struct MyCustomDataset : IEnumerable<float> {
    public float v1;
    public float v2;
    public float v3;

    public MyCustomDataset(float v1, float v2, float v3) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.v3 = v3;
    }

    // Enumerable impl
    public IEnumerator<float> GetEnumerator() {
        yield return v1;
        yield return v2;
        yield return v3;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

And methods like this:

```
public static MyCustomDataset test() {
    return new MyCustomDataset(1,2,3);
}

public static void test2() {
    MyCustomDataset ds = test();
    /* doing stuff with ds */
}
```

I want to know if its more optimal then if MyCustomDataset was class instead of struct. I need to know that, because im calling test() in apps main loop, so MyCustomDataset is going to be allocated in every apps iteration. Because of that, i wont make MyCustomDataset an class, because it would be like performance suicide. Im cosidering using struct, because im suspecting that it can behave more or less like primitive type in that case.

Would it be ok with performance ?

Im not going to assign MyCustomDataset to any class field, I will only read it in methods body, and maybe will pass it into a few method calls, so it will be present in few local scopes.

Comment: Simple answer: why don't you measure times yourself if you already know where the bottleneck might be?

Comment: Side note: Your struct is of a kind many people will call _mutable_. Consider making the three fields `readonly` (so `public readonly float v1;` and so on). If you need to change an individual coordinate (say `v1`) in an instance of `MyCustomDataset`, then maybe you should make it a class, since mutable structs can be confusing.

Comment: Yep, i forget about it but thats what i was thinking of too. Thx for notice ;]

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: An exposed field struct is basically a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape.  If the purpose of a struct is simply to bind some variables together with duct tape so they may be passed as a group, an exposed-field struct will be a perfect fit.  Microsoft guidelines presuppose that structs should try to act like classes, but getting optimal performance from structs requires using them differently.  Something like `Point` should have semantics totally different from `Decimal`; the former should be an exposed-field struct and the latter not.

Comment: @supercat I know that's your opinion, and I'm sure one can write excellent code that way, but a lot of people is of a different opinion, which is: never "expose" the fields of a struct, that is, never allow the fields to change values after the constructor has finished. The asker can of course make up his own mind about this. It's not illegal to make mutable structs, but many people disourage it.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Structs with mutable *properties* were horribly problematic at the time MSDN's original guidelines were written, and are still dubious; the fact that "struct property setters are evil" was taken to imply "all mutable structs are evil". I'd argue that using mutable class types to pass *values* is far worse. If `g` is a `Drawing.Graphics`, how can one tell, other than experimentation, whether `var t=g.Transform; t.OffsetX += 10;` will affect `g`? If it `Drawing2d.Matrix` were a struct with exposed field `OffsetX`, one wouldn't have to guess--one would know that it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You:

> because it would be like performance suicide

Why do you think so? What difference between structs and classes are you refering to?

I think you should go with a struct if you feel it's more or less like "a primitive type" (your words). This is just three `float` values (possibly a total of 96 bits), so it's small enough for a value type. But if you stick to a struct, make the fields `readonly`.

Comment: Well, dozens of object per second isnt good for performance, because GC will have to run cleaning very often, and garbage collecting is rather aggravating for processor, isnt it ?

Comment: @Fisher You can make millions of little objects on the heap every second, and the garbage collector will have no problems with that. But try for yourself. My advice is to choose between `struct` or `class` based on the semantics of your "object", and whether you want it copied and passed by value or by reference. If performance should be a problem later, first measure and analyze where the bottleneck is. It might be something other than your `MyCustomDataset` values/objects.

Comment: Yeah, i talked to my friend (that is much better coder then me :P) yesterday about it, and he said exactly the same = im unnecessarily worring about performance so much.